# Check multiple values in a select statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

Given a table with sales like this:

```
| PRODUCT_ID | USER_ID |
|------------|---------|
|          1 |       1 |
|          2 |       1 |
|          3 |       1 |
|          3 |       2 |
|          4 |       2 |
|          1 |       3 |
|          3 |       3 |
```

And a table with products and manufacturers like this:

```
| PRODUCT_ID | MANUFACTURER_ID |
|------------|-----------------|
|          1 |               1 |
|          2 |               1 |
|          3 |               2 |
|          4 |               2 |
```

How can I find the users that have bought all products from a manufacturer? I know I can use

```
SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE MANUFACTURER_ID = x
```

to find which products belong to a manufacturer x, but I don't have any idea as to how to continue from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write the query like this:

```
select s.user_id
from sales s join
     products p
     on s.product_id = p.product_id
where p.manufacturer_id = x
group by s.user_id
having count(distinct s.product_id) = (select count(*)
                                       from products
                                       where manufacturer_id = x
                                      );
```

Answer (score 1):

This selects all users where a product from a certain manufacturer that they have not bought does not exist - therefore they have bought all of that manufacturer's product.

```
select t1.user_id from (
    select user_id from sales s 
    join manufacturers m on s.product_id = m.product_id
    where manufacturer_id = x
    group by user_id
) t1 where not exists (
    select 1 from manufacturers m
    left join sales s on s.product_id = m.product_id and s.user_id = t1.user_id
    where m.manufacturer_id = t1.manufacturer_id       
    and s.product_id is null    
)
```

Edit

Another way is to select all users that have purchased all products

```
select t1.user_id from (
    select s.user_id, count(*) cnt from product p
    join sales s on s.product_id = p.product_id
    where p.manufacturer_id = x
    group by s.user_id
) t1 join (
    select count(*) cnt from product 
    where manufacturer_id = x
) t2 on t2.cnt = t1.cnt
```